# Files placed in directory with wordpress 404

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, outside-wordpress

I changed my WordPress permalinks settings from the default to displaying the name of the post. When I did this, all the files that I had been storing in the directory with WordPress (www.example.com/notpartofwp.html) suddenly displayed wordpress style 404 errors.

1. Is this normal WordPress behavior?
2. If so, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

in short this is normal ... i guess you added stuff to your .htaccess file between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`

What happened when you changed the permalinks is that WordPress changed that section of the .htaccess file.

So you need to open and insert the rewrite rules into your .htaccess file - BUT not between the WordPress tags

I hope you have a backup copy of the old .htaccess file?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I was trying to rewrite a separate /file.php to /file and I think the wordpress rewrites are interfering with my rewrite. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: @fdsa Please post your current `.htaccess` file's content to see what could be done to prevent the 404 error.

Comment: @fdsa Move your custom rewrites above the WordPress rules, and add the [L] modifier to any rewrites you do so as to make that the "last" rewrite modifier when it matches.